Getting error like {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
I have created NLB and VLC link, to target my alb traffic. If my alb is public, REST api-gateway link is working properly.
E.g.  https:ayp-gateway-stage-url/dev-alb/test/heathcheck   is giving proper response "200" but if my alb id private, same configuration is not working.
https://dev-alb/test/heathcheck is my healthcheck uel of api service deployed in ecs cluster. I have configured NLB and vpc-link in api-gateway and deployed api. The endpoint url I got in stage is https:ayp-gateway-stage-url/,  after hitting https:ayp-gateway-stage-url/dev-alb/test/heathcheck   I am getting response 200. But same I did for private alb , then getting error,  {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
